# Dynamic add and remove field using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have been working on a way to implement functionality where when a user presses a button he/she can add and remove fields. However, right now I am stuck at something. Here is a [link](https://codepen.io/sahil-sharma/pen/wEYxWb) to CodePen of what I have. I am using Bootstrap and some custom CSS to accomplish this.

The problem is that the remove record button removes the button below the div instead of the div right next to it. If the remove button is next to record 2 it should delete record 2, but my solution deletes record 3. I cannot find a way to achieve what I want using my solution i.e. using Bootstrap. Is there a way to accomplish this using my solution? Is there any other way to do this?

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
    crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
    <button class="newBtn collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample0">

        <!--You can put any valid html inside these!-->
        <span class="if-collapsed">Add Employment Record</span>
        <span class="if-not-collapsed">Remove Record</span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample0">
        Record 1
        <button class="newBtn collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample1">

            <!--You can put any valid html inside these!-->
            <span class="if-collapsed">Add Employment Record</span>
            <span class="if-not-collapsed">Remove Record</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample1">
        Record 2
        <button class="newBtn collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample3">

            <!--You can put any valid html inside these!-->
            <span class="if-collapsed">Add Employment Record</span>
            <span class="if-not-collapsed">Remove Record</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample3">
        Record 3
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**CSS**

```
[data-toggle="collapse"].collapsed .if-not-collapsed, 
[data-toggle="collapse"]:not(.collapsed) .if-collapsed
{
  display: none;
}


.collapse.show{
  display:flex;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any restrictions of using technologies?  You can achieve this much easily using javascript/Jquery ?

Comment: I don't have any restrictions. I thought it would be a lot more difficult using javascript/jquery. Bootstrap has built in hide and show feature.

Comment: If you don't have restrictions, use jquery/javascript if the goal is to get the job done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your method you can achieve your goal by changing some HTML structure like below:

```css
.newBtn.collapsed {
  display:block;
}
.newBtn {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
    <button class="newBtn collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample0">
        <span class="if-collapsed">Add Employment Record</span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample0">
        Record 1
        <button class="removeBtn collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample0">Remove Record</button>
        <button class="newBtn collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample1">Add Employment Record</button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample1">
        Record 2
        <button class="removeBtn collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample1">Remove Record</button>
        <button class="newBtn collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample3">Add Employment Record</button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample3">
        Record 3
        <button class="removeBtn collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample3">Remove Record</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed